# Elementary number theory sum of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let the sum of the divisors of  a number $N$ be equal to $s$(excluding N itself) then show that if $s=N$ then show that N is a perfect number.

I tried to use the basic formula for sum of divisors but that surely didn't work out anything. Can anybody please give me some hints as to how to prove the given statement.

Comment: How do you define a perfect number?

Comment: For, say, $N=6$, which divisors do you count ? $d=1,2,3,6$, or only $1,2,3$, or only non-trivial divisors $2,3$ ?

Comment: @almagest  "A positive integer N is said to be perfect if N is equal the sum of all its positive divisors excluding N itself . " Also the sum of divisors of a perfect number is twice the number .Copied from the answer given below by

Comment: I copied the definition from the answer given below by @Shona

Comment: @DietrichBurde the question requires us to count $d=1,2 and 3$. Now I have made the necessary edit regarding exclusion of N.

Comment: @HarshSharma So what exactly is the question? Are you asking why if $N$ satisfies the definition of a perfect number it is a perfect number?

Comment: @almagest i got it in the form of the question but now I came to know that this is actually the definition of a perfect number and the question gives the answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Hint$ : By the definition of a perfect number ; "A positive integer N is said to be perfect if N is equal the sum of all its positive divisors excluding N itself . "
 Also the sum of divisors of a perfect number is twice the number .

Comment: If that's the actual definition then I think the question has already been solved because it says to prove that N is a perfect number and the conditions it gives are actually that of the one explained by you. So Is this actually an explanation? I am asking this because I got this in the form of the question.

Comment: @Harsh Sharma Your question is the answer itself and yes this is the actual definition of a perfect number .

Answer (score 1):

$$N=P_1^{\alpha_1}\times\,P_2^{\alpha_2}\times\,...\times\,P_k^{\alpha_k}$$

$$\sigma(N)=\sum\limits_{d|n,d\ne\,N}{d}=\frac{1}{2}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}{\sigma (P_{i}^{{{\alpha }_{i}}})=\frac{1}{2}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}{\frac{P_{i}^{{{\alpha }_{i}}+1}-1}{{{P}_{i}}-1}}}$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Please.Good  luck

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of *all the divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  For example, $$\sigma(12) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 12 = 28.$$

If we let $s(x) = \sigma(x) - x$, then $s(x)$ is the sum of the *aliquot parts* of $x$.

Suppose that $s(N) = N$.  Then we have
$$\sigma(N) - N = N$$
which implies that
$$\sigma(N) = 2N.$$
This last equation is the definition of a **perfect number**, in terms of the classical sum-of-divisors function $\sigma$.